# cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'---- Heroku site this after deployment

Tags: python, heroku, mapping

i am uploading my files on heroku

site got uploadede but when i click on the link it shows "Application Error". In the logs it is showing "cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'"

```
' 2022-06-14T11:01:55.555207+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/defaults.py", line 32, in <module>
2022-06-14T11:01:55.555207+00:00 app[web.1]:     from jinja2.tests import TESTS as DEFAULT_TESTS

2022-06-14T11:01:55.555208+00:00 app[web.1]:    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/tests.py", line 13, in <module>
2022-06-14T11:01:55.555208+00:00 app[web.1]:     from collections import Mapping

2022-06-14T11:01:55.555208+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)

2022-06-14T11:01:55.555296+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-14 11:01:55 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)

2022-06-14T11:01:55.673034+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-14 11:01:55 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master

2022-06-14T11:01:55.673121+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-14 11:01:55 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

2022-06-14T11:01:55.831278+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3

2022-06-14T11:01:55.885638+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For a workaround with legacy Python code, I found adding the following to the `\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py` *from* section resolves the problem.

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
from collections.abc import Sequence
```

Additionally if your project .py file still has the legacy code line `import collections` replace it with the new code line `from collections.abc import Mapping`